# Using Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension Resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I am trying to use the **azurerm_virtual_machine_extension** resource in a Terraform template and am trying to understand what the "**name**" Argument should be.  The documentation says "**The name of the virtual machine extension peering. Changing this forces a new resource to be created**" but quite honestly, I am not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "name" should be anything you would like it to be. its just a name.

> The name of the virtual machine extension peering. Changing this forces
>   a new resource to be created

This means that if you change the name a new extensión will get created (instead of updating the old one).